# PHP maile utf-8 message without polish sings

Tags: php, utf-8, phpmailer

I have problem with UTF-8 coding in mail.

I have simple code, but every time if send mail its problem with polish sings.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    $select = $_POST['select'];
    $subject = $_POST['email'];

    $mailTo = "moje@op.pl";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    $body = "Dane kontaktowe: $name.\n".
            "Email: $mailFrom.\n".
            "Data: $date.\n".
            "Godzina: $time.\n".
            "Zabieg: $select.\n";

    



    mail($mailTo, $subject, utf8_encode($body), $headers);
    header("Location: reserv.php?mailsend");
  }

?>
```

Comment: Why are you working in ISO-8859-1 to start with? Why not UTF-8 all the way?

Comment: PHPMailer defaults to ISO-8859-1 because PHP itself does not guarantee that the mbstring extension is available, and that’s needed for UTF-8. Meanwhile, 8859-1 I think contains enough chars to handle Polish. The big problem here is that *you’re not using PHPMailer*, which takes care of all this for you.